# Why isn't this constexpr in a variadic function template constant?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

In my class (which is a variadic class template), I need a `constexpr` for the `sizeof()` of the largest type passed in a variadic template. Like this:

```
template<class... Types>
class DiscriminatedUnion
{
.
.
.
static constexpr auto value = maxSizeOf<Types...>();
```

The code I have come up with for `maxSizeOf()` is the following:

```
template <class T>
static constexpr T static_max(T a, T b) {
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

template <class T, class... Ts>
static constexpr T static_max(T a, Ts... bs) {
    return static_max(a, static_max(bs...));
}

template <class T>
static constexpr int maxSizeOf() {
    return sizeof(T);
};

template <class T, class... Ts>
static constexpr int maxSizeOf() {
    return static_max(sizeof(T), maxSizeOf<Ts...>());
};
```

But in Visual Studio 2017, I am getting a compile error "expression did not evaluate to a constant."

I am not sure what it is that is not allowing the expression to be constant. I've tried compiling different things to ensure that they can be constant. I've tried using a `sizeof()` with a template parameter in a `constexpr` function, which works, which I expect since the size of types is always known at compile time. Integer arithmetic and comparison seems to be valid in a `constexpr` function, but I tried some again for verification. Then I've tried using integer arithmetic in the variadic template method, without `sizeof()`, with the following:

```
template <class T>
static constexpr int maxSizeOf(int n) {
    return n;
};

template <class T, class... Ts>
static constexpr int maxSizeOf(int n) {
    return static_max(n, maxSizeOf<Ts...>(n + 1));
};

static constexpr int numBytes = maxSizeOf<Types...>(1);
```

And this does not work. So I'm thinking it must be something to do with the variadic method template expansion. But this should be able to be made a compile-time constant, because variadic template packs are always expanded at compile time. Does anyone know why these can't be `constexpr`?

Comment: Not an answer but FWIW you can use `std::max` for this like `static constexpr value = std::max({sizeof(Types)...});`.  live example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/LXdwbuKfJgeFngGW

Comment: It looks like MSVC gives several output errors on code which attempts to instantiate `maxSizeOf` (missing from this question, by the way), and the one you quote is the last one.  Be sure to read the full output, or if there are too many to understand, usually the *first* one is the most relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It compiles now, but the other errors had to do with finding the correct variadic function call, which I thought wasn't a problem because I was setting up this variadic function the same way I set up every variadic function. Also, due to my hardware limitations, I can't make use of the standard library. My apologies for forgetting this information in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"expression did not evaluate to a constant." seems not the root cause. Your `static_max` and `maxSizeOf` need modifications to make the compiler happy. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641495/ambiguous-call-to-variadic-template-function-with-no-parameters) to see how to do that under different C++ standards.

For example :

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
static constexpr T static_max(T a, Ts... bs) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return std::max(a, static_max(bs...));
}

template <class T, class... Ts>
static constexpr int maxSizeOf(int n) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) == 0)
        return n;
    else
        return static_max(n, maxSizeOf<Ts...>(n + 1));
};
```

Actually, we don't need `static_max` at all. All we need here is to find the max within just 2 values, and `std::max` is already there.

EDIT: it seems that we don't need `maxSizeOf` either... as Nathan mentioned in the comments, `std::max` can deal with `initializer_list` as well.

Comment: This looks good. I forgot to mention earlier that I can't use functions like `std::max` in my code, and I would also like to not be dependent on C++17 if possible, but this is a fine C++17 solution that can be adapted to not use `std::max` pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of your code is that when you call `max_sizeof<T>()` with a single `T` types, both

```
template <class T>
static constexpr int maxSizeOf() {
    return sizeof(T);
};
```

and

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
static constexpr int maxSizeOf() {
    return static_max(sizeof(T), maxSizeOf<Ts...>());
};
```

matches. So the compiler can't choose the correct one.

You can solve with `if constexpr ( sizeof...(Ts) )`, as suggested by dontpanic, but `if constexpr` is available only starting from C++17.

A possible (and elegant, IMHO) solution, working also in C++11 and C++14, is delete the only-one-type function and add the following zero-type function

```
template <int = 0>
static constexpr std::size_t maxSizeOf()
 { return 0u; };
```

This way when you call `maxSizeOf<Ts...>()`, when `sizeof...(Ts) > 0u`, the one-or-more-type version is called; when `sizeof...(Ts) == 0u` (that is: when the `Ts...` list is empy), the `int = 0` (no types) matches.

Onother suggestion: `sizeof()` is a `std::size_t` value so is better if `maxSizeOf()` return a `std::size_t`

The following is a full working (also C++11) solution

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
static constexpr T static_max (T a, T b)
 { return a < b ? b : a; }

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
static constexpr T static_max (T a, Ts ... bs)
 { return static_max(a, static_max(bs...)); }

template <int = 0>
static constexpr std::size_t maxSizeOf()
 { return 0u; };

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
static constexpr std::size_t maxSizeOf()
 { return static_max(sizeof(T), maxSizeOf<Ts...>()); };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct foo
 { static constexpr auto value = maxSizeOf<Ts...>(); };

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << foo<int, long, long long>::value << std::endl;
 }
```

But, as observed by aschepler (thanks!), this solution works but doesn't use at all the variadic version of `static_max()`.

An alternative, that uses the variadic version of `static_max()`, is rewrite the variadic version of `maxSizeOf()` not in a recursive way but simply unpacking the variadic list as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
static constexpr std::size_t maxSizeOf()
 { return static_max(sizeof(Ts)...); }
```

Now is the ground case (the zero-type version) of `maxSizeOf()` that isn't used anymore and can be deleted.

Anyway, as suggested by NathanOliver, you can use `std::max()` (the version receiving an initializer list) that, starting from C++14, is `constexpr`.

So, starting from C++14, you can simply write

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Ts>
struct foo
 { static constexpr auto value = std::max({sizeof(Ts)...}); };

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << foo<int, long, long long>::value << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Your full C++11 solution doesn't use the variadic `static_max` at all.

Comment: @aschepler - you're right... I've corrected the code of the question and I din't noticed it at all... thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. I am not sure why the single-parameter variadic didn't work, it always works. In fact, I didn't even know that you could do zero-parameter variadics like this. Thanks for pointing this out!